Movie about 3 (or more) people trying to get off snow covered mountain...?
Hope someone might know this one...
All I can really remember was that towards the end of the film, only 3 people are left, a father, his son, and a woman, who I don't remember how she was related to the father and son.
Anyway, they're trying to get off a snow covered mountain, blizzards etc., and one scene towards the end I can remember the father and woman manage to get across a ravine, but the son falls to his death trying to cross a snow bridge that collapses under him.
At the end, I think the father and woman walk on down to safety.
I have in my head that Kirk Douglas was the father, but I can't pick out the film from his list at IMDB.

The Mountain (1956)
They are two brothers, not father and son, and they find a girl on the mountain. And it is not Kirk Douglas, but Spencer Tracey.
Plot on Wikipedia:

"When they reach the downed plane, they find one badly injured
  survivor, an Indian woman (Kashfi). Chris wants to leave her there to
  die, but Zachary insists on bringing her down the mountain."
"On the descent, Chris, ignoring Zachary's warning, tries to cross an
  unsafe snow bridge and falls to his death."

Here is a clip that shows the younger brother's death. At the end of the clip you can see the snow bridge collapsing and the younger brother falling into the crevasse:




Why the downvote?

Wasn't me that downvoted. I actually made a post to say thanks less than 10 minutes after yours, but it seems to have disappeared. Thanks again!
